# Can I return collection and then use BelongsTo Model Relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a sponsors table that will have the following columns:

```
id
name
country
```

I have a clinical_trials table that will have the following columns:

```
id
name
status
country
```

I have a sponsor_to_clinical_trials table that will look like this:

```
sponsor_id (fk to sponsors table)
clinical_trial_id (fk to clinical_trials table)
```

A sponsor will be able to have many clinical trials, so for example a given sponsor_id will show up multiple times in the sponsor_to_clinical_trials table.

My question may be very basic, but I've only used model relationships where I return one item and then use the relationship.

I am not sure if something like this will work:

SponsorToClinicalTrial::where(sponsor_id, auth::guard('sponsor')) --> clinicalTrials-->contracts-->get()

SponsorToClinicalTrial::where(sponsor_id, auth::guard('sponsor')) will be returning a collection and there will be a 'belongsTo' relationship on the SponsorToClinicalTrial model called clinicalTrials that will go to clinical trials.

I know this would work if SponsorToClinicalTrial::where(sponsor_id, auth::guard('sponsor')) returned just one row, but I don't know if I can use this if it returns multiple rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table structure indicates that there is a many to many relationship between `sponsors` and `clinical_trials` via `sponsor_to_clinical_trials`. A basic `belongsToMany` relationship could be all you are looking for.

`Sponsor` model would have a `belongsToMany` relationship with `ClinicalTrial` model. And, `ClinicalTrial` model would have a `belongsToMany` with `Sponsor` model.

```
class Sponsor extends Model{
  public function clinicalTrials(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(ClinicalTrial::class, 'sponsor_to_clinical_trials');
  }
}

class ClinicalTrial extends Model{
  public function sponsors(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Sponsor::class, 'sponsor_to_clinical_trials');
  }
}
```

Now you can get all sponsors with related clinical trials, or a single sponsor with related clinical trials. Same is true for clinical trials.

```
//use App\ClinicalTrial; use App\Sponsor;
$sponsorsWithClinicalTrials = Sponsor::with('clinicalTrials')->get(); //list (collection) of sponsors with related clinical trials

$clinicalTrialsWithSponsors = ClinicalTrial::with('sponsors')->get(); //list of clinical trials with related sponsors

$singleSponsorWithClinicalTrials = Sponsor::where(id, auth::guard('sponsor'))->with('clinicalTrials')->get(); //your example, assuming auth::guard('sponsor') holds a sponsor id. 
//$singleSponsorWithClinicalTrials->clinicalTrials would give you the collection of clinical Trials belonging to that sponsor
```

More information on Laravel's many to many implementation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

What about making a [BelongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps) relationship between sponsors and trials:

```
class Sponsor extends Model
{
    public function clinicals()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ClinicalTrial::class, 'sponsor_to_clinical_trials');
    }
}
```

Then, you are able to access the `contracts` this way using [flatMap](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-flatmap) and [higher order messages](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#higher-order-messages):

```
$sponsor->clinicalTrials->flatMap->contracts;
//or
$sponsors->flatMap->clinicalTrials->flatMap->contracts;
//This is similar to the second example but more performant.
$sponsors->load('clinicalTrials.contracts')->flatMap->clinicalTrials->flatMap->contracts;
```